# showing listview JSON AsyncTask value on android

Tags: android, json, listview

I use `listview`

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

adapter.add("JSON RESULT VALUE");
adapter.add("JSON RESULT VALUE");
adapter.add("JSON RESULT VALUE");

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and JSON my source.

```
private TextView textView;
String strData = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   new JSONGet().execute();
}
private class JSONGet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls);
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
       String result = "";
       try {
           URL url = new URL("my server url");
           urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

           int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

           if (code == 200) {
               InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
               if (in != null) {
                   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                   String line = "";

                   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
                        result += line;
                   }
                   in.close();     
                }
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return result;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
             JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
             for (int i= 0; i< arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObeject jo = arr.getJSONObject(i);
               strData += jo.getString("name") + jo.getString("age");
             }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.d(TAG,"TTT");
        } 
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText(strData);
```

but this setJSON is showing textView.
 I want showing listView.

how to combination listview and JSON TEXT?

Comment: Im sorry but what is your problem?

Comment: Post your JSON response

Comment: @RafaelCardoso     sorry.  recently, I get JSONparser, my web server   textview. but I want showing listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting the result of async task to a text view inside onPostExecute method replace it with my suggestion. you need to add those results to list adapter and set that adapter to the list.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        try {
             JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
             for (int i= 0; i< arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObeject jo = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            String   strData = jo.getString("name") + jo.getString("age");
           adapter.add(strData);
             }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.d(TAG,"TTT");
        } 
       // textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
      //  textView.setText(strData);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the data to listview adapter instead of concat the result into a single string !

You can modify `onPostExcecute` as follow

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    try {
         JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
         for (int i= 0; i< arr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObeject jo = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            adapter.add(jo.getString("name") + jo.getString("age"));
         }
    } catch (JSONException e){
        Log.d(TAG,"TTT");
    } 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged():
}
```